# Why is "locally of finite type" stable under faithfully flat descent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a following cartesian diagram of schemes.
$$\begin{array}
AX^{'} & \stackrel{v}{\longrightarrow} & X \\
\downarrow{f'} & & \downarrow{f} \\
Y^{'} & \stackrel{u}{\longrightarrow} & Y  
\end{array}
$$
If $u$ is faithfully flat and quasi-compact and $f'$ is locally of finite type, then why is $f$ locally of finite type?

Wedhorn's book says that it follows from next lemma:

> **Lemma**: Let $A \rightarrow A'$ be a faithfully flat ring homomorphism, let $B$ be an $A$-algebra, and write $B' = B \otimes_A A'$. If $B'$ is $A'$-algebra of finite type, then $B$ is $A$-algebra of finite type. ("algebra of finite type" means finitely generated algebra)

The property of being locally of finite type is local on the target and the source. Hence we may assume that $X$ and $Y$ is affine. However, can we assume that $Y'$ is affine? Does there exist some affine open subsets $U$ of $Y'$ such that $u|_U : U \rightarrow Y' \stackrel{u}{\rightarrow} Y$ is surjective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one may assume that $Y'$ is affine. Every fpqc covering of an affine scheme admits a refinement to a covering of the same scheme by affine opens (see [stacks 022E](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/022E) for a source). One may base change along this refinement to get a new cartesian square with $Y'$ affine preserving the property that $f'$ is locally of finite type.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I see that if $\{ u \}$ is fpqc covering, then we may assume that $Y'$ is affine, but is $\{ u \}$ fpqc covering in the sense of [stacks 022E]?  I think this question is equivalent to the question that "Does there exist some affine open subsets $U$ of $Y'$ such that $u|_U : U \rightarrow Y' \stackrel{u}{\rightarrow} Y$ is surjective?"

Comment: A faithfully flat and quasi-compact map $u:Y'\to Y$ is a fpqc covering by definition. Your claimed equivalence (with a corrections: the collection of $U$ must form an open cover of $Y'$) is exactly the result I am telling you in my answer.

Comment: I cannot think that $u$ is fpqc covering is clear. Is your definition of fpqc covering the same as [stack 022B](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/022B)? If so, could you tell me more hint about it?

Comment: fpqc is an abbreviation for "fidelement plat et quasi-compact", French for "faithfully flat and quasicompact". Since $u$ is faithfully flat and quasicompact, that would seem to settle things. Alternatively, the _next lemma_ in the stacks project, 03L7, applied to our situation, shows the result.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for spending time with me!